# Resetting basic-authenticate-with

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, logout

I am trying to do a very basic authentication. I've already tried the one ryan bates used in his screencast with bcrypt-ruby and user authentication.

For a really small project I want to use something else:

```
http_basic_authenticate_with :name => 'user', :password => 'secret'
```

I've got a global called **$admin** and I've got a method to set its value to **false** (similar to logout).

Is there a way to reset this authentication so that the user (admin) has to fill in the "login credentials" again?

Kind regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately in case of `basic_auth` the user stays logged in until the browser window is closed. If user logs in with `basic_auth`, the browser stores the authentication information, and sends the authentication parameters through the http headers with every request.

There is a small catch to this though:
After logging in with `basic_auth`, when user goes browsing though your app and goes from one link to another (e.g. from `http://appdomain.com/link1` to `http://appdomain.com/link2` he is really going from `http://username:password@appdomain.com/link1` to `http://username:password@appdomain.com/link2`. The browser hides the `username:password@` part in you addressbar, so you do not know about it.
A dirty way to logout a user that has authenticated through basic_auth would be to create a link or redirect to http://invaliduser@appdomain.com/ that the browser does not hold authentication credentials to...
EDIT: or as an alternative redirect AND login a user into a no-privilege account that cannot view or do anything within your app through `http://guest:password@appdomain.com`

Hope it helped.